# How to create a query that compares an XML data to another table?

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to create a query where you get the results by comparing XML data in one table and the data in another?

Say for example I have an table like so:

```
StudentRecord Table

StudentID| Student_Name  |   ScoreData
         |               |
 1       |   Mathew      |    <Root><Math><Score> 10 </Score></Math> </Root>
```

And in the other table I have a list of passing score

```
Subject Table

SubjectId   |   Subject_Name  |   Passing_Score
            |                 |
   1        |   Math          |         50
```

In pseudoCode I did something like this

```
SELECT
    Student_Name
FROM StudentRecord sr
WHERE 
Data.value('/Root/Math/Score.Value', 'varchar(max)') >= S.Passing_score
```

The pseudoCode might make it more confusing. But the general idea is that I want to get all the students who scored at least 50 and above, which is based from the subject table.

I'm not sure if this can even be done in the first place.

Comment: It might be simpler to just dump the XML values into a table, then you can simply join like normal.